# archive_cleanup_command does not clear the archived wal files

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-13

**Main question:**
archive_cleanup_command in the postgresql.conf file does not clear the archived wal files. How can I get it to clear the archived wal files?

**Relevant information:**

- My OS is Linux, Ubuntu v18.04 LTS.
- Database is Postgresql version 13

**My current settings:**
/etc/postgresql/13/main/postgresql.conf file:

```
wal_level = replica
wal_compression = on

wal_recycle = on
checkpoint_timeout = 5min

max_wal_size = 1GB
min_wal_size = 80MB

archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'pxz --compress --keep --force -6 --to-stdout --quiet %p > /datadrive/postgresql/13/wal_aerchives/%f.xz'

archive_timeout = 10min

restore_command = 'pxz --decompress --keep --force -6 --to-std-out --quiet /datadrive/postgresql/13/wal_archives/%f.xz > %p'

archive_cleanup_command = 'pg_archivecleanup -d -x .xz /datadrive/postgresql/13/wal_archives %r >> /datadrive/postgresql/13/wal_archives/archive_cleanup_command.log 2>&1'
```

archive_cleanup_command.log has 777 permissions.

I have a master database doing logical replication with a publication and a slave database subscribing to that publication. It is on the slave that I am intending to do the archiving and restore points.

**What am I expecting to happen?**
The checkpoint timeout setting in the postgresql.conf file means that a restart point is created atleast every 5 mins. And the archive_timeout setting of 10 mins means that postgresql forces a logfile segment switch after every 10 mins. Therefore, atleast every 10 mins, a restart point is created. Whenever a restart point is created, the archive cleanup command is run. When this command is run it will clear all the .xz files older than this restart point. Therefore the wal_archives directory should not really have .xz files older than 20mins or even 2hours....

**What is actually happening?**

- The `/datadrive/postgresql/13/wal_archives` directory piles up with lots of .xz files that never get cleared.
- `cat archive_cleanup_command.log` shows an empty file. Nothing is ever writing to it.
- When I run the pg_archivecleanup command manually via bash, it works (i.e. clears all the archive files before the one specified and cat archive_cleanup_command shows the files that were cleared.
  Example:

  ```
   pg_archivecleanup -d -x .xz /datadrive/postgresql/13/wal_archives 000000010000045E000000E5 >> /datadrive/postgresql/13/wal_archives/archive_cleanup_command.log 2>&1
  ```

  Then running `cat archive_cleanup_command.log` gives this:

  ```
   pg_archivecleanup: keeping WAL file "/datadrive/postgresql/13/wal_archives/000000010000045E000000E5" and later
   pg_archivecleanup: removing file "/datadrive/postgresql/13/wal_archives/000000010000045E000000DE.xz"
   pg_archivecleanup: removing file "/datadrive/postgresql/13/wal_archives/000000010000045E000000DF.xz"
   pg_archivecleanup: removing file "/datadrive/postgresql/13/wal_archives/000000010000045E000000E0.xz"
   pg_archivecleanup: removing file "/datadrive/postgresql/13/wal_archives/000000010000045E000000E1.xz"
   pg_archivecleanup: removing file "/datadrive/postgresql/13/wal_archives/000000010000045E000000E2.xz"
   pg_archivecleanup: removing file "/datadrive/postgresql/13/wal_archives/000000010000045E000000E3.xz"
   pg_archivecleanup: removing file "/datadrive/postgresql/13/wal_archives/000000010000045E000000E4.xz"
  ```

**What have I tried?**

- I have tried various permission settings (examples: chmod 777 the wal_archive directory, add other users to the postgres group, etc...)
- Extensively and thoroughly read the postgresql documentation and looked atleast 20 different related stackoverflow posts.
- Initially tried 7zip cmd line tool to do the zipping instead of pxz.
- Successfully restarted the database multiple times using the following commands:

  ```
   sudo systemctl stop postgresql@13-main
   sudo systemctl start postgresql@13-main
  ```
- Dropped the logical replication and re-created the publication on the master and subscription on the slave.
- Enabled checkpoints on the master itself.
- Looked at `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-13-main.log`. Unfortunately no relevant errors show up in this log.

Comment: pxz does not have an option "--to-std-out".

Comment: Have you looked at the log file on the replica, or just on the master?

Comment: @jjanes pxz I believed --to-std-out option as a valid option for pxz as the documentation says it is compatible with xz. The docs I am referring to are here https://linux.die.net/man/1/pxz and here https://linux.die.net/man/1/xz . The archiving part has been tested on my system and I can confirm that it works.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Sorry, I have missed out on the fact that it needs to be in recovery mode. I am not in recovery mode. My setup is a standard setup with just the settings above. I have a master database doing logical replication with a publication and a slave database subscribing to that publication. It is on the slave that I am intending to do the archiving and restore points. I am new to databases and lack a good understanding of how recovery and restart points work in pgsql. Are there any good sources on the web that you know of that can get me started in the right direction?

Comment: @jjanes I have looked at the log file on the replica as that is where I am trying to setup the archive and restartpoints and that is where I have successfully setup the archive system. I haven't done anything on the master db.

Comment: The best source of information is the PostgreSQL documentation.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I find things are not obvious/clear in the documentation....for example....it doesn't directly say that restartpoints, restore command, etc...only apply to streaming replication. You have to figure this out in a very round about way...

Comment: These configuration settings are listed under "recovery configuration", are they not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restartpoints, `restore_command` and `archive_cleanup_command` only apply to streaming ("physical") replication, or to recovery in general, not to logical replication.

A logical replication standby is not in recovery, it is open for reading and writing. In that status, recovery settings like `archive_cleanup_command` are ignored.

You will have to find another mechanism to delete old WAL archives, ideally in combination with your backup solution.

Comment: Thank you so much Laurenz! You're the best.